Running ROS2 in docker on OSX - net=host not being able to see nodes on other non docker machines on network
Hi there I am running osrf/ros:jazzy-desktop-full in a docker on OSX(m1) using net=host and have verified that network is working by sending some OSC messages to a python script running in the docker from an external machine. (not the host)
However I am not able to see any ros2 nodes running on external machines on the same network.
Host networking is enabled using docker desktop, though still a beta feature on OSX.
I start the docker like this:
docker run -it --rm --platform linux/amd64 --name ros2_container_with_osc \
--net=host \
--ipc=host\
--pid=host\
-v $PWD:/Ros2_wk/src \
ros2_osc_to_topic_docker \
bash

Any tips?
Thank you.
Best
Thor
